# Customizing checkout flow in shopify with a security question

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I am pretty new to shopify and have created a simple store that contains a list of products. What I would like to provide is a set of predefined security questions that the user have to fill to complete the checkout flow. The docs didn't provide much clarity on this. Is it supported by shopify?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. But if you wanted to subscribe to Plus, you could put a little quiz into play. Probably not a good idea though.

What do you mean by Security questions anyway? Like, are you an adult? If that is all you care about, you do that when the customer first lands on the shop, because there and then, it is easy to have a quiz, and take action. Like locking the customer out from shopping.